# Can I force the use of an assembly name on xmlns:local in xaml?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

In a .xaml activity references to types in the same assembly use the namespace 'xmlns:local' without the assembly reference like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar"
```

Since there's no assembly my unit tests which load the xaml fails, my code, in a third assembly (an Azure Worker Role) can't load it either since it doesn't know which assembly the namespace belongs to.

Is there anyway I can force the xmlns to reference the assembly like this (and all other xmlns in the xaml-file):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar;assembly=Foo"
```

If I add the `;assembly=Foo` manually it works but Visual Studio keeps deleting the assembly string when I change something.

Comment: So, you're loading activities from text in the unit test?  You might have to break that apart so that your unit tests can deal with already loaded assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot force the LocalAssembly.

You could just reference the assembly and use the activity that way.  Or, if you are loading .xaml files you can specify the LocalAssembly by using a XamlXmlReader.

I've added a class to the latest version of [Microsoft.Activities.Extensions](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview&referringTitle=Documentation/) called XamlHelper that does this for you but here is how it works

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a XAML or XAMLX file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlFile">
    /// The xaml file. 
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="localAssembly">
    /// The local assembly. 
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The activity or root activity of a WorkflowService 
    /// </returns>
    public static Activity Load(string xamlFile, Assembly localAssembly)
    {
        Contract.Requires(localAssembly != null);
        if (localAssembly == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localAssembly");
        }

        var readerSettings = new XamlXmlReaderSettings
            {
                LocalAssembly = localAssembly, 
                AllowProtectedMembersOnRoot = true
            };

        var xamlType = GetXamlType(xamlFile);
        switch (xamlType)
        {
            case WorkflowXamlFileType.Activity:
                using (var reader = new XamlXmlReader(xamlFile, readerSettings))
                {
                    return ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader);
                }

            case WorkflowXamlFileType.WorkflowService:
                using (var reader = new XamlXmlReader(xamlFile, readerSettings))
                {
                    return ((WorkflowService)XamlServices.Load(reader)).GetWorkflowRoot();
                }

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid file extension on xamlFile");
        }
    }
```